# A particular product of distributions

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose you have two continuous functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$; is the product $f'g$ as a distribution, at least locally? I am interested in a local result, actually, so you can as well assume that $f$ and $g$ are compactly supported.

Obivously, $f'$ is, as $f\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$.

Moreover, I am aware of the following particular cases:

1. if $f\in W^{1,1}(I)$, then $f'g$ is well defined on $I$
2. if $f'\in L^p(I)$ and $g\in L^q(I)$ for $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, then $f'g$ is defined on $I$;
3. if $g\in W^{1,1}(I)$, then again $f'g$ is well defined on $I$

I am interested in a general result or in a counterexample. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited after questioner's clarifications: The analogous question for functions on a *circle* is somewhat easier to answer decisively, since all distributions are tempered (and have Fourier series expansions), and since the index for Fourier series is discrete. Further, the *local* question on the line or on $\mathbb R^n$ reduces to the analogous question on products $\mathbb T^n$ of circles, since we can smoothly truncate.

The $L^2$ Levi-Sobolev spaces $H^s$ on the circle [or products of circles, similarly] can be characterized/defined as distributions $u$ with Fourier coefficients $\hat{u}(n)$ satisfying $\sum_n (1+n^2)^s\cdot |\hat{u}(n)|^2<\infty$. A distribution (provably) lies in some $H^s$, so has Fourier coefficients of polynomial growth. [This is true on $\mathbb T^n$.]

The product of two Fourier series, one in $H^s$ the other in $H^t$, certainly converges for $s+t\ge 0$, and converse, I think, by Banach-Steinhaus/uniform-boundedness. [Similarly on $\mathbb T^n$.]

While (Levi-Sobolev imbedding) $H^{1/2+\epsilon}\subset C^o$, and while Fourier series of functions in $H^{1/2+\epsilon}$ converge uniformly pointwise to the functions, Baire category (and Riemann-Weierstrass counterexamples) show that the converse fails significantly. [Edit:] The traditional Baire category argument to prove that *typical* continuous functions' Fourier series fail to converge to them pointwise (hence, note, are in no $H^{1/2+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$), as in http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes 2012-13/05b_banach_fourier.pdf does not produce an explicit function, but is perhaps more compelling/persuasive. I hesitate somewhat to try to recap the Riemann-Weierstrass explicit versions, unless "explicit example" is essential to your/the-questioner's context.

Thus, in terms of the Levi-Sobolev spaces, for $f$ continuous but *not* in $H^{1/2}$ [or not in $H^{{\rm dim}/2}$, for $\mathbb T^n$] there should exist many $g\in C^o$ such that the apparent Fourier series product for $f'\cdot g$ does not make sense because the expression for the $0th$ coefficient diverges (beyond repair).

(If this kind of answer is interesting/useful, I can amplify it and worry about the details.) [Edit:] a bit added, per request...

Comment: As I am mainly interested in the question locally, I could think of $f$ and $g$ as compactly supported functions (thinking about it, I shall edit the question accordingly!). So I think they could be seen as functions on $S^1$ (don't they?). I have more or less followed your argument and I'm quite persuaded, I just can't figure out exactly how to produce a counterexample. Actually,  I didn't really put myself on it ... anyway, if you already have a clear idea on how it should be, it would be helpful. And, obviously, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just a random thought: I know that there are some funny ways of defining products of distributions (the wavefront set, the Colombeau algebra and so on), but I do not know much more about them ... Would it maybe be possible to define the product I asked about in one of those contexts?

Comment: Yes, in two or more dimensions, hypotheses on non-intersecting wavefront sets can allow legitimate products of distributions, basically for sensible physical reasons. Similar things can be reflected in a local/Fourier series discussion, too, by deliberately avoiding blow-up of Fourier coefficients of products. As a trivial example, $\sum_{m,n} {\sqrt{|m|}\over 1+n^2}\cdot e^{imx+iny}$ and $\sum_{m,n} {\sqrt{|n|}\over 1+m^2}\cdot e^{imx+iny}$ can be multiplied (I think).